# Is it possible to integrate Cypress 12 with Cucumber BDD?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cucumber, cypress, bdd

I tried to configure Cypress 12 with Cucumber using the instructions below:
https://testersdock.com/cypress-cucumber-bdd/

Has anyone had any success with this? I had been getting constant errors and Cypress will not run my feature file. I'm thinking I may need to go back to Cypress 10 to get this to work. Many thanks.

Comment: That information is well out of date and buggy. You want to follow [badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor) for straight forward and up-to-date information.

Answer (score 2):

In cypress 12 you should add your preprocessors along with the `spectPattern` on the `cypress.config.js` file, in this way you'll be able to use cucumber with it:
Documentation -> https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/preprocessors-api

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default;

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
    specPattern: '**/*.feature',
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('file:preprocessor', cucumber())
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Don't use that NPM package, it is no longer supported. The correct package is given by @Lola Ichingbola